# Red5 without adobe flash player

Tags: adobe, flash, red5, live-streaming

Is it possible to do live streaming using Red5 server without adobe flash player ? The thing is i want successfully installed Red5 server and worked out demos. I wanted to improve the video quality by utilizing VP8 codec (h.264 licensing issues..so passed that). Now Adobe flash player does not support VP8/Webm as of now. So my question is

**Is streaming possible without flash player ? any other alternative ?**

Answer (score 0):

Once we get WebRTC integrated, you'll no longer need flash; this however will not happen any time soon. Your other option is to use Xuggler in Red5 and do HLS or RTP streaming.

Comment: Will Red5 integrate WebRTC in near future?

Comment: A commercial produce based on Red already exists which supports WebRTC, HLS, RTSP, etc... http://red5pro.com/